# How does an Excel cell handle null data using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Using apache poi, I make Excel data reading logic.
but, the output data comes out incorrectly because the null value is not processed.
What should I do here?

```
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {

                    case NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print((int) cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t"); 
                    break;
                    case STRING:      
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
```

Comment: What value is `null`? What output data do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: There is a case where the empty value is exceeded in the Excel.

ex)
1:A 2:null 3:B 4:C      ---> 1:A 2:B 3:C

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the check of null value in the cell.

```
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();

        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            if(cell==null) {
               System.out.print("nothing"+ "\t");
               continue;
            }
            switch (cell.getCellType()) {

                case NUMERIC:
                System.out.print((int) cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t"); 
                break;
                case STRING:      
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
```

Comment: I tried it. but it's the same...

Comment: give please stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void readXLSFileWithBlankCells() {
    try {
        InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream(EXCEL_FILE);
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);

        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow row;
        HSSFCell cell;

        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
            
            for(int i=0; i<row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
                cell = row.getCell(i, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                System.out.print(cell.toString()+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

thanks to @madan712 (https://gist.github.com/madan712/5611191)

but if there are 13 cells at total but the 13rd cell doesnt contain value so `row.getLastCellNum()` still misses the last cell

my solution is storing a value for lastCellNum at a global field, base on the header of the table like `final int totalCol = headerRow.getLastCellNum()` then the cells loop would be `for(int i=0; i<totalCol; i++)`